# How can I count the number of sleeping processes in my system?

Tags: command-line, scripts, process

How can I count the number of sleeping processes using a shell script?

Comment: Ok I need to write a shell script with a menu and one of the required is that ( Sleeping Process.
(Running this task will count the number of sleeping process in your system) ) it is a sub- menu from process management

Comment: Ah, like here: https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-11-linux-process-states/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extended explanation... trusting you to take it all in since it's your homework...

List processes with the `ps` command

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4879 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 5003 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

Oh, this only shows the processes of the current session. We want to show all processes in the system. For that we can use the `-e` flag

```
$ ps -e
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:05 systemd
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
[and many more lines]
```

but how do we show which ones are sleeping??

You can use the `-l` option or `u` option. This gives more detail including the state of the process. Sleeping processes have a letter `S` or `D` in the STAT column

from `man ps`

> PROCESS STATE CODES
>          Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state
>   of a
>          process:
>
> ```
>            D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>            R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>            S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>            T    stopped by job control signal
>            t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
>            W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>            X    dead (should never be seen)
>            Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
> ```

We can format the `ps` output to show ONLY the states, to make it easier to count them:

```
ps -e -o state
```

here we use `-e` to get all the processes and the `-o` flag, followed by the type of output we want. This command outputs only the state letter. We can then pipe (using `|`) this output to `grep` to count the lines with `S` or `D`, the sleeping processes:

```
ps -e -o state | grep -cE 'S|D'
```

`grep` searches for text. The `-c` option tells it to only count matches instead of outputting the found text itself. The `-E` option tells `grep` to use extended regex, so that we can use the `|` characters to match thing OR stuff using the expression: `thing|stuff`. When using regex, use single quotes to prevent expansions by the shell.

Comment: Excellent. Even I understand.

Comment: Another option for the right side of the pipe is `grep -c '[SD]'`. (Each alternative is just a single character, so a character class is sufficient.)

Answer (score 5):

Very easy if you know that `ps` command outputs status for sleeping processes as either `S` for interruptible sleep and `D` for uninterruptible sleep, and you can use `-o s` flag to find the state of those. Now all you have to do is to run output through `grep` that will count occurrences of those flags. Like so:

```
$ ps -e -o s | grep -o 'S\|D' -c                                                                                         
260
```

Comment: Nice, never heard of a sleeping process before.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to list the number of processes in each state by using:

```
$ ps -e -o state | sort | uniq -c
  1 R
141 S
```

Comment: Please add a description of the states. Incluing "I"

Answer (score 0):

The `top` utility provides the number of tasks, showing how many are running, and how many are sleeping.  Of course, that changes on a moment-by-moment basis, but so would the output of any of these one-liners.  As with any *nix utility, the `man` page will give greater detail.

Comment: Although I don't know of a way to do this with `top` that's *simpler* than the `ps`-based method detailed in the other answers, `top` is indeed very powerful and you're right that the number of sleeping processes can be extracted from its output. I suggest `top -bn1 | sed -n 2p | grep -oP '\d+(?= sleeping)'`, though there might be a simpler way I haven't thought of that's as good or better. Please feel free to add that (with or without modification) to your answer as an example, if you like.